# MARS MIPS assembler gives error: Extended (pseudo) instruction or format not permitted

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

In Mars (an IDE for MIPS) I found really strange errors.  The sample code is like this

```assembly
.text
.globl main
  main : 
  la $a0, msg
  li $v0, 4
  syscall
.data
  msg: .asciiz "Hello World"
```

and the error message is:

> Extended (pseudo) instruction or format not permitted. See the Settings.

Comment: Any particular line giving the message?

Answer (score 4):

`LA` is a [Pseudo-instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Pseudo_instructions). The assembler translates `LA` into two MIPS instructions. You probably need to enable pseudo-instructions in your Mars settings, since it is very tedious to write MIPS assembler without using pseudo-instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Is a space allowed after your label on `main :`?  That is my guess.  Beyond that, perhaps you have saved the file with DOS line breaks instead of UNIX - or maybe it's a Unicode vs ASCII thing for your file format.  I'd also look for an extra "exotic" character on the line number the assembler specifies.

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't check to ensure the use of pseudo code

Answer (score 1):

Main menu, Settings -> Permit extended (pseudo) instruction and formats - need enable this checkbox in Mars v4.3.